# Upload de várias fotos usando o caminho da imagem (PHP e Mysql)

Tags: php, imagem, upload

Bom, estou tendo dificuldades em pegar a foto que o usuário escolhe no computador e jogar no banco de dados e depois joga-la em uma pasta criada no meu projeto para que eu possa exibir a imagem, já quebrei muito a cabeça, não sou expert em php, e preciso de ajuda nessa parte parte para concluir meu projeto.

**Aqui é o meu formulário html com o form!**
Lembrando que eu consigo inserir os dados de texto na minha tabela do banco. Só está faltando as imagens para que fique completo.

```
<form action="../routes/upload_anuncio.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cad_sucesso'])): ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        <?=$_SESSION['cad_sucesso'];?>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                <?php 
                endif; 
                unset($_SESSION['cad_sucesso']);
                ?>

                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['cad_err'])): ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <?=$_SESSION['cad_err'];?>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                <?php 
                endif; 
                unset($_SESSION['cad_err']);
                ?>
                    
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Funcionário:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="post_funcionario" placeholder="Nome do Funcionário" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['nome_funcionario']; ?>" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Tipo de Anuncio:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="tipo_anuncio" required>
                                <option value="Aluguel" selected>Aluguel</option>
                                <option value="Venda">Venda</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Cidade:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="cidade" required>
                                <option value="Juazeiro do Norte - CE" selected>Juazeiro do Norte - CE</option>
                                <option value="Crato - CE">Crato - CE</option>
                                <option value="Barbalha - CE">Barbalha - CE</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>CEP</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cep" name="cep" placeholder="CEP" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Endereço:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="endereco" placeholder="Endereço" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>N°:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="num_casa" placeholder="123, 123 A" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Bairro:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bairro" placeholder="Bairro" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Visibilidade:</label>
                            <select class="form-control disabled" name="visibilidade">
                                <option value="Disponível" selected>Disponível</option>
                                <option value="Indisponível">Indisponível</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Telefone / Celular:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefone" name="telefone" placeholder="Telefone / Celular" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Whatsapp:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="wpp" name="wpp" placeholder="Whatsapp" required>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <br>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Foto da Fachada:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="ftfachada" class="form-control-file" multiple required>
                        </div>
                        <!--<div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Foto dos Cômodos:</label>
                            <input type="file" name="ftcomodos[]" class="form-control-file" multiple required>
                        </div>-->
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Valor:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="valor" name="valor" placeholder="R$ 0.000,00" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Este valor pode ser negociável?</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="valor_neg" required>
                                <option value="Sim">Sim</option>
                                <option value="Não">Não</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm">
                            <label>Quantidade de Cômodos:</label>
                            <select class="form-control" name="qtd_comodos" required>
                                <option value="3" selected>3</option>
                                <option value="4">4</option>
                                <option value="5">5</option>
                                <option value="6">6</option>
                                <option value="7">7</option>
                                <option value="8">8</option>
                                <option value="9">9</option>
                                <option value="10">10</option>
                                <option value="Mais de 10">Mais de 10</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
                            <button type="submit" name="salvar_anuncio" class="w-100 btn btn-anunciar btn-lg">Anunciar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

**Aqui está o código que processa todas as informações**

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    include "../config/conn.php";

    

        $post_funcionario   = $_POST['post_funcionario'];
        $tipo_anuncio       = $_POST['tipo_anuncio'];
        $cidade             = $_POST['cidade'];
        $cep                = $_POST['cep'];
        $endereco           = $_POST['endereco'];
        $num_casa           = $_POST['num_casa'];
        $bairro             = $_POST['bairro'];
        $visibilidade       = $_POST['visibilidade'];
        $telefone           = $_POST['telefone'];
        $wpp                = $_POST['wpp'];
        $ftfachada          = $_FILES['ftfachada']['name'];
        $valor              = $_POST['valor'];
        $valor_neg          = $_POST['valor_neg'];
        $qtd_comodos        = $_POST['qtd_comodos'];

            //pegar id do usuario cadastrado
            $id_user_anun = $_SESSION['id'];
            
            $query = "INSERT INTO criar_anuncio (nome_funcionario, tipo_anuncio, cidade, cep, endereco, numero_casa, bairro, visibilidade, telefone, wpp, foto_fachada, valor, valor_neg, qtd_comodos, id_user_anun, data_cadastro) VALUES ('$post_funcionario', '$tipo_anuncio', '$cidade', '$cep', '$endereco', '$num_casa', '$bairro', '$visibilidade', '$telefone', '$wpp', '$ftfachada', '$valor', '$valor_neg', '$qtd_comodos', '$id_user_anun', NOW())";
            $new_query = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            
            if (mysqli_affected_rows($conn) != 0) {
                $_SESSION['cad_sucesso'] = 'Anúncio Feito! Acesse o <b>Painel</b> ou o seu <b>Perfil</b> para visualizá-lo.';
                header("Location: ../pages/criar_anuncio.php");

            }else{
                $_SESSION['cad_err'] = 'Não foi possivel realizar o Anúncio! Tente novamente.';
                header("Location: ../pages/criar_anuncio.php");

            }

    $conn->close();
    exit;
?>
```

Eu realmente não sei como prosseguir, e ficarei no aguardo se alguém poder ajudar!

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=Php+upload+de+imagens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa questão de upload de arquivos existe diversos exemplos pela internet, sempre que possível tente dar uma pesquisada antes, caso não ache nada, faça sua pergunta.

Mas, vamos para a sua questão:

Vamos considerar o seguinte trecho HTML:

```
<form method='post' action='' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
   <input type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple>
   <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Upload'>
</form>
```

De acordo com a marcação acima, preparamos o formulário para receber múltiplos arquivos.

```
<?php
// Verificando se recebemos alguma informação através do POST submit 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // verificando a quantidade de arquivos enviado pelo formulário
    $countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
    // Tendo a quantidade de arquivos, é percorrido cada elemento
    for ($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++) {
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
        // Para cada imagem encontrada, ela é movida ao destino escolhido, no caso foi definido o diretório upload
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i],'upload/'.$filename);
    }
} 
?>
```

A referência do código descrito está disponível no site [https://makitweb.com/multiple-files-upload-at-once-with-php/#:~:text=In%20PHP%2C%20it%20is%20possible,element%20to%20select%20multiple%20files](https://makitweb.com/multiple-files-upload-at-once-with-php/#:%7E:text=In%20PHP%2C%20it%20is%20possible,element%20to%20select%20multiple%20files).

Demais questões, normalmente você nunca irá salvar a imagem no banco de dados, mas sim o caminho dela até o diretório.